# Maximum power test

Tags: self-study, p-value, likelihood-ratio

**Question:**
In a count that was held a year ago in a reserve , there were 15 tigers counted. 7 females and 8 males, which were marked with numbers from 1 to 15.

a. By recent reports, there was fear that the number of tigers in the reserve had dropped under 15. In order to check that, it was decided upon going out and recording the numbers of 4 tigers in the reserve, which will appear randomly. If the maximum number of these 4 records is k or lesser, then the conclusion is that the number of tigers really decreased.

1. if the count was done with return. what is the value of K, if the required p-value is 0.1?
2. If the count was done without return , calculate the p value of the test when k=9.

b. In a random sample of 4 tigers, without return , there was 1 male and 3 females found. Now we need to check if the first count (a year ago) had a mistake, and actually there are 15 tigers in the reserve but among them 8 females and only 7 males. 
1. find a maximum power test based on X - the number of females in a 4 tiger sample.
2. find the p-value of that test, and make a conclusion for a=0.1
3. find the probability of a type II error, and the power of the test.

**My thoughts**
I did part a, and wasn't sure about it.
about part b- didn't really know how to do it- is doing the ratio of likelihood functions a good way to start? I don't know what is the parameter for that though...

in A.1. i said that $X_i\sim U(1,15), S(X)=max(X_i)$. $P(S(x)\le k)=0.1$ so $0.1=\frac {k-1+1}{15-1+1}=\frac k{15}$ so $k=1.5$ -> $k=1 $(k has to be a whole number)
A.2. $P(S(x)\le9)=P(X_1\le9)P(X_2\le8)P(X_3\le7)P(X_4\le6)=\frac 6{65}$

Comment: yep. excuse my english... :-)

Comment: Ah, through math, problems seem so simple. :) There is a growing pile of literature on assessing tiger (and other feline species) numbers, especially in the spatial context. This is where you use spatial component of the data (where was the animal sighted?) to infer their home range, which you use to assess the actual area sampled, which is important for calculating density of animals. This (currently) takes hierarchical models and a butt load of field work. :)